# Is there a way to check who or what is causing a redirect?

Tags: php, apache, redirect

My project (using a complex framework/cms) does redirects based on PHP, .htaccess, JS etc... and Iam struggling to find who is causing a specific redirect. While I see the redirect using common tools (RedirectChecker, Browser-Dev-Tools ...) I cannot see who/what is causing it. Is there a general way to find out e.g.

- foo.de     -> 301 -> www.foo.de (.htaccess line:4711)
- www.foo.de -> 301 -> www.foo.com/de/ (somefile.php line:666)

Note: I have access to the server.

Comment: Disable all redirect except the one you want to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot check from client side, how the `server-sided redirection` is triggered. What you can do, however, is that you can add custom `HTTP Headers` everytime you redirect.

Example in PHP:

`header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently by PHP script');`
should show up in Firebug or other inspector tool.

Alternative (haven't tried) is:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Redirected from index.php');
```

Comment: Yes, there is parts within the cms/framework, that does so (php-wise), not all though, and unfortunately I cannot modify each and every redirect. Is there no such thing like a trace for that kind of things? It might be enough to see whether the redirect is perfomed by PHP, JS, HTML-meta, or .htaccess.

Comment: You can track JS and HTML redirects, just use some plugins for your browser to disable JS and META-redirects and you will know. 

As of server sided redirects, all you can do is edit every redirect and add cutom header that will tell you more.

Answer (score 0):

For .htaccess redirects you can turn on Rewrite loggin [RewriteLog](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteLog). For php rewrites what you can do is force output to the browser (see [`flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) and [`ob_flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php)). An error will be generated when the framework try's to set headers, for example the location header.

You can also take a look at [`override_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) to overwrite the header function, check if location header is send and log it to file or throw an exception or error. You can get the trace using [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php). You will `PECL apd >= 0.2` to use `override_function`

Answer (score 0):

A radical (but in some sense the most correct) way to handle that is to replace all occurrences of `header()` in your project with `my_header()` and write `my_header` so that it logs its parameters and passes them down further to php's `header`. If your FW uses namespaces, you can simply add your own `header` to the NS.

If you cannot change the FW code, you'll need runkit or sorts to hook on the global function.